# Validation (Page_ClientValidate('mygroup')) returns always true after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, telerik

i have a page which i do some validations , all my validations are client side expected one which it use server validation. So my problem is when i fire the server side validation and the page postbacks, this function Page_ClientValidate('mygroup') return true, so i lose my validation though my required fields aren't.

```
function DoValidation() { var validated = Page_ClientValidate('NewMemberRequired'); Page_BlockSubmit = false; return validated; }

<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save & Close" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true"
                                OnClientClick="return DoValidation();">

//the fields 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AddressRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Address"
                        CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Required"ValidationGroup="mygroup"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator/>

//an other filed with postback=true
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="age" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="age_TextChanged">
```

Comment: You should do both client AND server side validation on all post-able fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. read the documentation on using RadButton's client-side events as your approach will not work even if it does not cause errors: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientclicking.html. This can also help: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/12-08-10/migrating-onclientclick-handlers-from-asp-button-to-telerik-s-asp-net-ajax-button.aspx
2. Read the documentation on executing custom validation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-validation-with-postback-confirm.html
3. Make sure your validation grops are fine because in the provided snippet they do not match
4. the AutoPostBack=true for a textbox will have it postback when you delete its text, regardless of the validator in this setup

Here is some code that validates well:

```
        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save & Close" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true"
                           OnClientClicking="DoValidation">
        </telerik:RadButton>
        //the fields
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AddressRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Address"
                                    CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="mygroup">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        //an other filed with postback=true
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="Address" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="age_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="mygroup" CausesValidation="true">
        </telerik:RadTextBox>

        <script>
            function DoValidation(sender, args) {
                var validated = Page_ClientValidate('mygroup');
                args.set_cancel(!validated);
                Page_BlockSubmit = false;
            }
        </script>
```

Changes:

1. proper use of OnClientClicking event
2. proper ValidationGroups being set
3. CausesValidation=true for the etxtbox so deleting its text will cause validation and prevent the postback

Comment: +1 I'm not using telerik but this solved my issue anyway as I didn't have `causesValidation` on my controls and had passed the name of the form instead of the validationGroup to `Page_ClientValidate()`. Just a good example of setting up validation. I didn't realise I had messed it up so bad as it still seemed to work fine except for `Page_ClientValidate` always being `true`